# Panel Control Paint Event not working for User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I created one Windows Forms User Control, I drag, dropped a panel inside it and over the panel I drew the graph in the Paint event of Panel.

```
private void pnlViewer_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(pnlViewer.AutoScrollPosition.X, pnlViewer.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds);
    //**draw Y Axis**
    int y;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        y = (i * cellHeight) + cellHeight;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50)),
                            new Point(0, y), new Point(pageWidth, y));
    }
    //**draw X Axis**
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        x = (i * cellWidth) + ribbonWidth;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50)),
                            new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, pageHeight));
    }
    DrawWaveForm(e.Graphics); **// Here the actual data of graph will draw**
}
```

When I drag this user control onto a WinForm, it calls this paint event of User Control from windows form, but while calling to this event the graph is shown but after some time the graph becomes blank.

I tried `Invalidate(true), Update(), Refresh()` all such methods but they were of no use.

Actually it shows half of the graph over form and after next the same paint event is fired then it shows the full graph that I require, but actually I want on first Paint event instead of half graphs showing the full graph.

Comment: How do you draw in `DrawWaveForm()` without passing a `Graphics` object?

Comment: @Andy sorry just i forget to add it thanks for to show my silly mistake also update the code thanks ones again........

Comment: Is this solved now by correcting that mistake?

Comment: @JohnWillemse it draw the graph and after some time panel inside the form show me blank...

Comment: You should not have to call `Invalidate()`, `Update()` or `Refresh()`. Do you use `g.Clear()` anywhere?

Comment: I have updated Question please check it.....

Comment: @Andy I ddin't use these methods

Comment: Try a PictureBox or use the user control itself and set DoubleBuffered property to true for it.

Comment: @MahanGM I tried DoubleBuffered Prop. but its not works

Comment: @user2404595 Are you painting on user control or panel right now? And I'm not sure that the problem is from painting or not. Maybe there is another thing you're keep loosing at the first run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50)),
                        new Point(0, y), new Point(pageWidth, y));
```

You are not disposing the System.Drawing object in this code.  Possibly in other code as well.  This can go unnoticed for a long time, the garbage collector tends to hide the problem.  But if it doesn't run often enough then the operating system can get sulky about you using so many GDI handles and it won't allow your program to create any more of them.  The quota is 10,000 handles, a very large number but easily consumed if you repaint often.  Typical when you draw a constantly updating graph for example.  What happens next varies, somewhere between an exception and noticing that your program doesn't paint correctly anymore.

Always use the *using* statement in painting code to avoid this failure mode:

```
using (var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50))) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, y), new Point(pageWidth, y));
}
```